# Jmeter - how can I process input files with fixed column length?

Tags: jmeter

anyone have a best practice to process txt input files with fixed column length in Jmeter? One idea I had was to pre-process and add commas and then use the CSV plugin but it went complicated. The file format comes from a TPC-DI benchmark with the first five (of 37) columns like below!

```
19670126-034131CMPXdCwDlGsXFstGqdCIcNOKJfTOQPnoEeELXbNmwOl                    0000000020ACTVHMAA- 191711032579 Creekbend Way
19670206-040729CMPIiHkvFAHjNrDbHaXULOVQWMsfQI                                 0000000028ACTVOOA+  1900062921605 Gaston Boulevard
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to specify whatever delimiter you want in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

[image]

however if the file really looks like you provided and the number of whitespaces between columns is different and a "cell" can contain whitespaces as well like `Gaston Boulevard` you could really convert these varying whitespaces into fixed delimiter using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) so you won't have to manually pre-process the file each time you ingest new data.